# Reverse words with exclusion rules

Tags: swift, string, reverse

I would like to get a func which will be able to reverse a string without affecting special characters, preferably using regex, ex:

Input: “Weather is cool 24/7” -> Output: “rehtaeW si looc 24/7”

Input: “abcd efgh” -> Output: “dcba hgfe”

Input: “a1bcd efg!h” -> Output: “d1cba hgf!e”

I was able to write only for all characters without exceptions, I'm a beginner, and I don't know how to use regexes

```
func reverseTheWord(reverse: String) -> String {

    let parts = reverse.components(separatedBy: " ")
    let reversed = parts.map{String($0.reversed())}
    let reversedWord = reversed.joined(separator: " ")
    return reversedWord
}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: What counts as a "special character"? Everything except a-z and A-Z?

Comment: Here's a strategy. Consider the word as a sequence of characters occupying positions, like playing cards face up on a table. Extract the normal characters in order, leaving the special characters occupying their positions. Reverse the extracted characters and deal them back into the empty positions.

Comment: is your actual requirement to reverse every word in the in a string, not the string as a whole, while while retaining all non-aphabetical characters in their current positions?

Comment: Or do you want "words" with special characters excluded from being reversed?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution where I first check what type each word is, only letters, no letters or a mix of letters and other characters and handle each differently.

The first two are self explanatory and for the mix one I first reverse the word and remove all non letters and then reinsert the non letters at their original position

```
func reverseTheWords(_ string: String) -> String {
    var words = string.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces)

    for (index, word) in words.enumerated() {
        //Only letters
        if word.allSatisfy(\.isLetter) {
            words[index] = String(word.reversed())
            continue
        }

        //No letters
        if !word.contains(where: \.isLetter) { continue }

        //Mix
        var reversed = word.reversed().filter(\.isLetter)            
        for (index, char) in word.enumerated() {
            if !char.isLetter {
                index < reversed.endIndex ? reversed.insert(char, at: index) : reversed.append(char)
            }
        }
        words[index] = String(reversed)
    }

    return words.joined(separator: " ")
}
```

Comment: Nice use of keyPaths.  I always forget you can do that and go for the closure.